# Ошибка Application Error в Heroku при входе на админ. сайт Django

Tags: python, django, heroku

После успешного развертывания интернет-магазина на Heroku при входе на админ сайт Django выдает ошибку Application Error с кодом H13 (это я посмотрел в logs).
Ошибка происходит именно когда хочу зайти на админ. сайт Django. Суперпользователя в Heroku при развертывании приложения я создавал.

Внятного решения проблемы я не нашел.
Буду благодарен за любую помощь.
Внизу прикреплю скрин ошибки[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В моем случае нужно было в requirements.txt изменить версию Django с 3.1 до 2.2.10.